# Printing in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, printing, uwp

I'm using PrintManager class for printing in UWP application. In which I want to print data in Rows and columns. I created a grid control in code behind and tried to pass that grid to SetPreviewPage() and I set it to Preview Page. But I face issue when data become too much and it doesn't get rendered to next page.

I also tried to render this data on RichTextBlock but I'm unable to arranging data in rows and columns and show border.

Is there anyway by which I can render data on multiple print preview page using grid control.

Here is the code for creating Grid

```
 public Grid FormatData()
    {
        CreateLayoutGrid(PickLists);
        PopulateData();

        ParentGrid.Children.Add(ChildGrid);
        Grid.SetColumn(ChildGrid, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(ChildGrid, 3);
        return ParentGrid;
    }


    private void PopulateData()
    {
        var row = 0;
        var column = 0;

        CreatePageHeader();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            CreateCells(item , ref row, column);
            column = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }

    private void CreatePageHeader()
    {
       ------

        Grid.SetColumnSpan(pspsServices, 3);
        Grid.SetRow(pspsServices, 0);

        Grid.SetColumn(control1, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(control1, 1);

        Grid.SetColumn(control2, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(control2, 1);

        ParentGrid.Children.Add(control1);
        ParentGrid.Children.Add(control2);
    }

    private void CreateCells(model items, ref int row, int column)
    {
        var top = row == 0 ? 1D : 0D;

        var descriptionBorder = new Border
        {
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, top, 1, 1),
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
        };

        var quantityBorder = new Border
        {
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, top, 1, 1),
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
        };

        var emptyBorder = new Border
        {
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, top, 1, 1),
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            Width = 100
        };

        var description = (row % 30) == 0 ? CreateBoldTextBlock(Constants.Description)
            : CreateMediumTextBlock(pickList.Description);

        var quantity = (row % 30) == 0 ? CreateBoldTextBlock(Constants.Quantity)
            : CreateMediumTextBlock(pickList.QuantityOrdered.ToString());

        descriptionBorder.Child = description;
        quantityBorder.Child = quantity;

        ChildGrid.Children.Add(descriptionBorder);
        ChildGrid.Children.Add(quantityBorder);
        ChildGrid.Children.Add(emptyBorder);

        Grid.SetRow(descriptionBorder, row);
        Grid.SetRow(quantityBorder, row);
        Grid.SetRow(emptyBorder, row);

        Grid.SetColumn(descriptionBorder, column++);
        Grid.SetColumn(quantityBorder, column++);
        Grid.SetColumn(emptyBorder, column);
    }

    private void CreateLayoutGrid(List<PickListItemsModel> pickLists)
    {
        var firstColumn = new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        };

        var secondColumn = new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = GridLength.Auto
        };

        var thirdColumn = new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        };


        ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(firstColumn);
        ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(secondColumn);
        ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(thirdColumn);

        ParentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
        {
            Height = GridLength.Auto
        });

        ParentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
        {
            Height = GridLength.Auto
        });

        ParentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
        {
            Height = GridLength.Auto
        });

        ParentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        CreateColumnsInChild();

        foreach (var pickList in pickLists)
        {
            ChildGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }
    }

    private void CreateColumnsInChild()
    {
        ChildGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star)
        }); 

        ChildGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        ChildGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }

    private TextBlock CreateBoldTextBlock(string text)
    {
        return new TextBlock
        {
            FontSize = 14,
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            Text = text,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 5, 10, 5)
        };
    }

    private TextBlock CreateMediumTextBlock(string text)
    {
        return new TextBlock
        {
            FontSize = 14,
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Medium,
            Text = text,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 5, 10, 5)
        };
    }
```

[image: Here is the print format]

Answer (score 0):

See the Official [Printing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) sample and look at the `PrintHelper` class, you will find how it adds the new page to display from the `AddOnePrintPreviewPage` method.

It is similar for your this issue, you can try to use your own Grid page to replace the `PageToPrint` page in the sample.

**Update**

You can try to use the [RenderTargetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap) class to render your Grid to image, then print the images in different pages as the Printing sample [Scenario5Photos](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Printing/cs/Scenario5Photos.xaml.cs).

Comment: I did the same thing but content of Grid doesn't flows to next page when content is more that means Data always renders to only one page regardless of amount of data.

Comment: I have added the update, could you try this scenario?